# Re-position custom filter on list report

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I've added one custom filter in my List Report application. I need to change its position in the Smart Filter Bar from 2nd to 5th.
Any help is appreciated.

Already tried changing the index under smartfilterbar > ControlConfiguration but it doesn't work.

Comment: Is it annotation based? that's a good place to start

Comment: No, we have added one custom filter from UI end using extension. Rest all other filters are coming from CDS view.

Comment: Yes, but does the CDS use annotations. There are annotations to tell what the position of the field is in both the selection and the table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`ControlConfiguration`** Class has a property `index` set it to the position you want in the `smartfilter`